# DOS/4GW Fatal Error (1307): not enough memory

Tags: c, windows, memory, dos, watcom

I'm trying to run a dos/4gw application in Win7 32 bit OS. I'm getting the following error message,
`DOS/4GW fatal error (1307): not enough memory`

When I run the same application in WinXP 32 bit OS, it works fine and no issues.

The dos/4gw application was built using the Watcom C compiler.

The mem command shows the following avaiable memory,

`655360 bytes total conventional memory
   655360 bytes available to MS-DOS
   580640 largest executable program size
 16777216 bytes total EMS memory
 16777216 bytes free EMS memory
 32505856 bytes total contiguous extended memory
        0 bytes available contiguous extended memory
 15580160 bytes available XMS memory
          MS-DOS resident in High Memory Area`

From the above it is clear that the memory is less than 1MB. However my program needs more than that. Basically I need to extend my DOS memory to get more than 1MB of memory for running my dos/4gw application.

Could any one please help in resolving this memory issue?

Thanks!

-Anand

Comment: Oh my.. look out of the window, it's 2017 out there. Where did you get this antique from? Anyway, try using DosBox.

Comment: I tried DosBox as well. I need to extend my memory more than 64 MB to run my application flawless. However DosBox does not support more than 64 MB in my system.

Comment: So which form of extended memory does the program use?

Comment: I believe there is a shim in recent versions of Windows limiting the available DPMI memory to 32 MB, for yet more ancient software incapable of unprepared such wast quantities of RAM. You may try creating a `DpmiLimit` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WOW` in the registry to adjust this with the limit in bytes as a DWORD.

Comment: @doynax Yes it worked. I'm able to run the DOS/4GW program without any memory issue. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is the reply sent by **doynax**:

`"I believe there is a shim in recent versions of Windows limiting the available DPMI memory to 32 MB, for yet more ancient software incapable of unprepared such wast quantities of RAM. You may try creating a DpmiLimit key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WOW in the registry to adjust this with the limit in bytes as a DWORD"`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to help preserve *why* this setting exists, before it's lost to history.

**Short Version**: Broken DOS extenders used 16-bit signed integers. Anything larger than 32,768 bytes (32 MB) will cause them to fail.

---

Thomas R. Nicely had a post in 2007 that points out the problem:

[**Windows Vista restricts non-Win32 apps to 32 MB of memory**](http://www.trnicely.net/misc/vista.html) *([archive](https://archive.fo/jhtm))*

And then [there's a 2010 usenet post that reminds](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/n5KbegKJuE0/ecYkxLdvuI4J) us that an operating system limiting the amount of memory available to DPMI:

- has existed since the beginning of virtual memory (e.g. OS/2)
- exists to prevent misbehaving DPMI applications from trying to allocate 2 GB of memory (because memory is virtual)
- [for old games you can find FAQs that give the DPMIs you should apply](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/os2-faq/dos-games/)

---

> I recently came across Thomas R. Nicely's WWW page on Windows Vista's
>   DPMI server.  It's pretty confused.  ([These people](http://justlinux.com./forum/showthread.php?p=866737) have some
>   quite sensible things to say on the matter of M. Nicely's page.)  And
>   no wonder that it is, if this was how you explained things to M.
>   Nicely, as xe claims you did.  (-:
>
> This DPMI server limit is another case in point, as a matter of fact. 
>   M. Nicely presents this as some sort of mysterious conspiracy against
>   gcc.  In actual fact, as pointed out by M. bwakaz, it's simple defence
>   against all of the stupid and broken things that DPMI-based extended
>   DOS applications are known to do, such as allocating all of the memory
>   that is available at program startup, because they are badly written. 
>   M. bwakaz points to [an article by Raymond Chen](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com./images/9780321440303/samplechapter/Chen_bonus_ch02.pdf) that anyone
>   wanting to understand this should read.
>
> This `DpmiLimit` setting that you mentioned is in fact nothing new. 
>   It's simply *undocumented* on Windows NT 6.  OS/2 VDM's have had a
>   *documented* DPMI memory limit setting for almost two decades.  The
>   setting is `DPMI_MEMORY_LIMIT`.  You can read on Usenet and the WWW
>   hundreds of discussions of this, going back to about 1994, and the
>   reasons for tweaking it up and down.  On an OS/2 system one can open
>   up a VDM settings notebook, and obtain on-line help describing the
>   setting.
>
> Raymond Chen singles out DOS games as some of the particular offenders
>   when it comes to abusing DPMI, and [there's a whole FAQ for running
>   DOS games under OS/2](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/os2-faq/dos-games/) that lists the various different
>   `DPMI_MEMORY_LIMIT` (and other) settings for getting such games to play
>   nicely with the operating system and not chew up memory unnecessarily,
>   just because the DPMI server in the VDM would otherwuse allow them to.
>
> Again, NTVDM isn't being "weird", at all.  It's implementing a
>   setting, and a limit, that is par for the course in Virtual DOS
>   Machines.  Even the default of 32MiB isn't unusual.  The default for
>   `DPMI_MEMORY_LIMIT` in OS/2 VDMs was (in recent versions of OS/2, if
>   memory serves) 64MiB.  If you read Raymond Chen's article all of the
>   way to the end, there's even an explanation of *why* such values are the
>   defaults: It's to cope with the *broken extended DOS programs* that
>   measure available DPMI memory in KiB using 16-bit integers.  (NTVDM's
>   default assumes signed 16-bit integers.  OS/2's VDM default assumes
>   unsigned 16-bit integers.)
>
> All of these things — be they traps into the VM monitor from inside
>   the VDM, or DPMI server limits to control badly written DOS programs —
>   aren't NTVDM being "weird" or unusual, or secret conspiracies by
>   Microsoft against people who think that compiling with gcc means that
>   one is compiling extended DOS programs.  They're simple long-standing
>   practice for VDMs, and run-of-the-mill stuff for virtual machine
>   technology that goes back for decades.